# Difference between Ondblclick And Dblclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am reading someone Else's javascript code which is listed below

```
window.onload = function(){
  // Listen to the double click event.
  if ( window.addEventListener ) {
    document.body.addEventListener( 'dblclick', onDoubleClick, false );
  }
  else if ( window.attachEvent ) {
  /* attachEvent is Microsoft and addEventListener is W3C */
    document.body.attachEvent( 'ondblclick', onDoubleClick );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the event is "dblclick" and the event (handling) property is called "ondblclick". even in IE the event itself is named "dblclick" ([**ref**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534697%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).)

Answer (score 0):

With or without the "on" it is the same event.

Historically, inline event handling via element attributes used the "on" event names:

```
<div id="div1" ondblclick="someFunction();">
```

Assigning the event handler within a script block also used the "on" names:

```
document.getElementById("div1").ondblclick = someFunction;
```

Microsoft's `attachEvent()` method (IE8 and lower) used the "on" event names:

```
document.getElementById("div1").attachEvent("ondblclick", someFunction);
```

But then the standards-based `.addEventListener` (IE9 and the other browsers) used the non "on" event names:

```
document.getElementById("div1").addEventListener("dblclick",onDoubleClick,false);
```

The code you've quoted first checks whether `addEventListener` is defined, which it will be for modern browsers including IE9, and if it isn't it then tries for `attachEvent`, which will be defined in older versions of IE. (Ironic that it goes to the trouble of using the modern methods for the `dblclick` event but uses the old style for the `.onload`.)